# CrashLytics not showing crash reason

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am using crashlytics in my app. It caught a crash in the app, but not telling the line of code where crash occured. It is showing the verify error, but not telling where it is. [This link is a screenshot to the report.](http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/7132/uuna.png) It is showing ??? about the crash, [see this link](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/2713/04la.png). How to study this crash now? ._.

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: I had the same problem when using obfuscation. When I talked to them they sad that I have to add `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable` to proguard file, witch I already had in my proguard file. With next build problem seam to disappear but today I noticed same problem again. I am currently talking to them trying to resolve the issue. I'll let you know if I find solution.

Comment: @blazsolar Thanks and hope your issue gets fixed. By the way, too enable proguard, I am just uncommenting this line in project.properties file:  proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Answer (score 0):

Preserve annotations, line numbers, and source file names

> -keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable

If you are using custom exceptions, add this line so that custom exception types are skipped during obfuscation:

> -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception 
>   -printmapping mapping.txt

To skip running ProGuard on Crashlytics, add the following.
This will help speed up builds so that we can ship and test even faster.

> -keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; } 
>   -dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

More Info: Follow this link to Configure Crashlytics with Proguard.

> https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html